# How to replace replace vowels with a special character in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class ReplaceVowels {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the String:");
        String str = bf.readLine();

        char[] c = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            if (c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'e' || c[i] == 'i' || c[i] == 'o'
                    || c[i] == 'u') {

                System.out.println(str.replace(c[i], '?'));

            }

        }

    }
}
```

why does the `str.replace` method not work? What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your code, you're creating a new array of characters, which is the same length as your string, but you're not initialising the array with any values.

Instead, try:

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray();
```

However, this isn't the best way of doing what you're trying to do. You don't need a character array or an if statement to replace characters in a string:

```
String str = bf.readLine();
str.replace( 'a', '?' );
str.replace( 'e', '?' );
str.replace( 'i', '?' );
str.replace( 'o', '?' );
str.replace( 'u', '?' );
System.out.println( str );
```

The `replace` function will replace any (and all) characters it finds, or it will do nothing if that character doesn't exist in the string.

You might also want to look into using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (as pointed out in edwga's answer), so that you can shorten those 5 function calls into one:

```
str.replaceAll( "[aeiou]", "?" );
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, `str.replace` will not modify original string, it will return new/separate one with modified content. You probably meant `str = str.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, this solution is relatively impractical. You should use the str.replaceAll() method instead.

```
(read in the String str);
str = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "?");
System.out.println(str);
```

What this does is it uses the regular expression "[aeiou]" and replaces it with a special character ("?"). Regex is a complicated topic, but this one just detects every instance of a vowel.
You can read more about Regex at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: you can also add `(?i)` in regex to make it *case insensitive* like `"(?i)[aeiou]"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to replace all vowels in a string with an "X".  The (?i) is to make it case insensitive.

```
String str = "hEllo";
str = str.replaceAll( "(?i)[aeiou]", "X" );
```

Could also be more explicit with case like:

```
String str = "hEllo";
str = str.replaceAll( "[aeiouAEIOU]", "X" );
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers works .
Just adding some case sensitivity to capture vowels in upper case(Using Scanner  Class)

```
       String str1, str2;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
       str1 = scan.nextLine();
       str2 = str1.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "?");
       // adding AEIOU to capture Vowels in uppercase.
       System.out.println("All Vowels Removed Successfully");

       System.out.println(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/***
 * Replace all vowels in an input string with
 * the corresponding numbers replace with 1,2,3,4,5
 * @author Kishore Diyyana
 */
public class ReplaceVowels {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReplaceVowels rv = new ReplaceVowels();
        System.out.println(rv.replaceVowels("Kishore Babu Diyyana"));
    }
    public String replaceVowels(String inputStr) {
        return inputStr.replaceAll("[aA]","1").
                        replaceAll("[eE]","2").
                        replaceAll("[iI]","3").
                        replaceAll("[oO]","4").
                        replaceAll("[uU]","5");
    }
}
```